# How to force Power BI to filter out individual records, rather than groups?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Power BI Desktop to create some table visualizations. Each record is a sales. I'd like to count up the total number of sales less than $200,000 in each department.

After trying to use a visual level filter it seems that Power BI is using it as a HAVING-clause (filtering out departments with less than $200,000 in total sales) rather than a WHERE-clause (filtering out individual sales worth less than $200,000).

How can I filter out individual records, rather than groups?

Comment: Can you show what the visual looks like and what columns and/or measures you are using to generate it?

Comment: Is your Value parameter the count of all records? If so, try using a quick measure to filter by amount < $200,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure:

```
Small Sales Count = COUNTROWS( FILTER('Sales', 'Sales'[Amount] < 200,000))
```

It filters 'Sales' table for the records where amount is <200,000, and counts rows in the result.